# Jquery changing color of a child in parent

Tags: jquery

how can I change the css of a specific child in  `$(this)`.

Right now it changes the color of the whole parent so are there any ways to do this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".info_td").click(function(){
            $(this).css({'width': '500px','background-color': 'grey'})
          })
    })
```

Comment: `$(this).children(childselector).css({'width': '500px','background-color': 'grey'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to do it via `jQuery`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".info_td").click(function(){
            $(this).children("div:eq(1)").css({'width': '500px','background-color': 'grey','margin':'2px 5px'})
          })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Column</td>
      <td class="info_td">
        <div>A1</div>
        <div>A2</div>
        <div>A3</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```